# Обнуляются переменные после завершения метода?

Tags: java

Здравствуйте! Хотел написать банкомат с использованием массива. Есть 3 варианта выбора:

1. Пополнить счет
2. Снять деньги
3. Забрать карту

Когда выбираю пополнить счет, метод работает, но вот когда уже хочу снять деньги, все данные, которые обработал первый метод, обнуляются.
Как тут быть ?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    while(true){
        System.out.println("Выберите:\n1. Пополнить счет  \n2. Снять наличные \n3. Вернуть карту");

        Scanner src = new Scanner(System.in);

        Bankomat bn = new Bankomat();

        int a = src.nextInt();

        if(a==1){
            System.out.println("Внесите сумму");
            int money = src.nextInt();
            bn.setCash(money);
        }else if(a==2){
            int money1 = src.nextInt();
            bn.getCash(money1);
        }else if(a==3){

        }else{
            System.out.println("Не правильний выбор");
        }
    }
}
```

```
public class Bankomat {
    private int cash;
    private int total;

    private int arr[] = new int [1];

    public void setCash(int cash){
        this.cash=cash; 
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            arr[i]=cash;
        }
        total=total + cash;
        System.out.println("На Вашем счету " + cash);
    }

    public void getCash(int cash){
        total= total-cash;
        System.out.println(total);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ты в цикле все время создаёшь новый объект `Bankomat bn = new Bankomat();` вынеси это за цикл `while`

Comment: Спасибо большое , все получилось)

Comment: Прошу обозначить мой ответ решением:) спасибо